# Add image to left column on homepage

Tags: image, templates, magento, themes, html

How do I add an image to the left column on the homepage?

Answer (score 3):

There's a simpler way of doing this:

1. in the admin go to CMS->Manage Pages
2. select the home page to edit it
3. on the left select the second tab(own layout)
4. as the layout choose either 3 colum or 2 column with left bar
5. in the xml changes field add this:

> ```
> <reference name="left">
>     <block type="core/template" name="unique.id" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
>         <action method="setImgSrc"><src>imageUrl</src></action>
>         <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>alternative text</alt></action>
>     </block>
> </reference>
> ```
>
> 6. in the xml field change "imageUrl" to the address of your image, "alternative text" to the alternative description and unique.id to a **unique** id like advertisement.banner.left.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the magento admin site, choose System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer and turn on template tag hints. (Make sure your store name is selected in the Current Configuration Scope dropdown)

You can then go back to your store homepage and you will be able to see which template is used for the left column.

Modify the .phtml template file and add your image there.